# I cannot seem to find the problem Exception thrown: write access violation. prime was 0x828753A3. C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently coding the sieve of Atkin in C++ and it is working well when I'm generating all prime numbers under 50 000 or so but when I try with 50 000 or more the error "Exception thrown: write access violation. prime was 0x828753A3." appears and I can't seem to understand why.

this error appears under the bloc of code where I get rid of multiple of k^2

```
//get rid of multiple of prime k^2
    //start at 5 to skip useless loop with 2 and 3
    for (int i = 5; i < n + 1; i++) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i * i) {
                prime[j] = false; //Exception thrown: write access violation. prime was 0x828753A3
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Atkins(int n) {
    bool* prime = new bool[n + 1];
    int nbr = 0;

    // set all value to false
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        prime[i] = false;
    }

    //test for all x y combination
    for (int x = 1; x*x < n; x++){
        for (int y = 1; y * y < n; y++) {
            //test three different algorithm possible
            int k = 4 * x * x + y * y;
            if (k <= n && (k % 12 == 1 || k % 12 == 5)) {
                prime[k] = !prime[k];
            }
            k = 3 * x * x + y * y;
            if (k <= n && k % 12 == 7) {
                prime[k] = !prime[k];
            }
            if (x > y) {
                k = 3 * x * x - y * y;
                if (k <= n && k % 12 == 11) {
                    prime[k] = !prime[k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //get rid of multiple of prime k^2
    //start at 5 to skip useless loop with 2 and 3
    for (int i = 5; i < n + 1; i++) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i * i) {
                prime[j] = false; //Exception thrown: write access violation. prime was 0x828753A3
            }
        }
    }

    //base prime number in list
    if (n >= 2) {
        cout << "2\n";
        nbr++;
    }
    if (n >= 3) {
        cout << "3\n";
        nbr++;
    }
    //print all prime number in list
    for (int i = 5; i < n + 1; i++) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            nbr++;
            cout << i << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "Il y a " << nbr << " nombre premier entre 0 et " << n << "\n";
    delete[] prime;
    system("PAUSE");
}
int main() {
    Atkins(50000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have used a debugger to locate where the crash happens, you should also be able to examine the values of all involved variables. What are the values of`i`, `j` and `n` when the crash happens?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, until it crashes, what did you see?

Comment: Hint: sqrt(INT_MAX) for 32bit signed int is 46340.95. Think about that.

Answer (score 2):

While you're properly guarded all accesses against too big index values, you didn't expect them to be negative.
By running the code under debugger you can see that when error happens, `n = -2146737495`.
Such value was cause by "integer overflow". When `i=46349 -> i*i= 2148229801`, which is more than int (32 bit) can take (2^31 - 1).
Simple way is to use `long long int` data type for multiplication (it has 64 bits, so max value is 2^63 - 1).

`int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i * i` -> `long long int j = (long long int)i * i; j <= n; j += (long long int)i * i`.

Comment: Since the numbers aren't supposed to be negative, why not use `unsigned` for all variables instead? Not only increases the range, but overflow is then well-defined (and will not risk being negative).

Comment: It's probably fine in this case, although I personally I avoid unsigned numbers given that conversion rules when mixing signed and unsigned values are very unnatural to me (like in: `(signed)-1 < (unsigned)1 == false`)

Comment: thank you for pointing out my integer overflow it works well now

Answer (score 1):

Several things you need to realize:

- On a 32bit platform, INT_MAX is 2147483647. The maximum natural root below that value is 46340 (e.g. root of x^2 = 2147395600.
- Automatic representation promotion isn't a language feature. I.e. if you have two `int` values `x=50000` and `y=50000`, the expression `x*y` is *still* `int`, but because of signed integer overflow, has platform-dependent results. You don't want that.

Yes, you can change the data types to larger 64bit representations, but you don't *have to* do that. To accommodate the above problem *and* considerably reduce your workload, understand that you should limit your loops without having to compute `i * i` or `j * j` as part of the conditionals. Rather, you can cap the top-end of those loops (and more) using the real thing you're trying to prevent: cross over the square root boundary of `n`.

For example:

```
for (int x = 1; x*x < n; x++){
```

Suppose there was a value `nr` that was the result of acquiring the integer portion of the square root of `n`. Then, would what you're really trying to do be better considered as:

```
int nr = sqrt(n) + 1;
for (int x=1; x < nr; ++x)
```

So lets do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void Atkins(int n)
{
    bool *prime = new bool[n + 1];
    int nbr = 0;

    // set all value to false
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        prime[i] = false;
    }
    
    int nr = sqrt(static_cast<double>(n)) + 1;

    //test for all x y combination
    for (int x = 1; x < nr; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < nr; y++)
        {
            //test three different algorithm possible
            int k = 4 * x * x + y * y;
            if (k <= n && (k % 12 == 1 || k % 12 == 5))
            {
                prime[k] = !prime[k];
            }
            k = 3 * x * x + y * y;
            if (k <= n && k % 12 == 7)
            {
                prime[k] = !prime[k];
            }
            if (x > y)
            {
                k = 3 * x * x - y * y;
                if (k <= n && k % 12 == 11)
                {
                    prime[k] = !prime[k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //get rid of multiple of prime k^2
    //start at 5 to skip useless loop with 2 and 3
    for (int i = 5; i < nr; i++)
    {
        if (prime[i])
        {
            for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i)
            {
                prime[j] = false; //Exception thrown: write access violation.
            }
        }
    }

    //base prime number in list
    if (n >= 2)
    {
        cout << "2\n";
        nbr++;
    }
    if (n >= 3)
    {
        cout << "3\n";
        nbr++;
    }
    //print all prime number in list
    for (int i = 5; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        if (prime[i])
        {
            nbr++;
            cout << i << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "Il y a " << nbr << " nombre premier entre 0 et " << n << "\n";
    delete[] prime;
}
```

Executing the above version of that function should deliver the results you seek.

[See it live here](https://ideone.com/ny7lFk)

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix it worked well